# How do I add additional information to my questions?

Tags: comments, discussion

When someone answers my question saying that I need to provide some additional information to better solve my quandry, how should I go about that?

Do I add those details as a comment to their answer or do I add them in the main body of my question?

If I add details only as a comment, then other supporters, those that will be looking through my question, may not notice them. Especially given the fact that some comments are hidden and you can only see them if you click on "Show one more comment".

On the other hand, if I add those details only in the upper section of the page (i.e. that section where the question itself is stated), then those who have already responded to my question and inquired for additional information might stay unaware of the update as many of them, as far as I know, would only return to my question if they are notified by the system of some responses that came as comments directly to their answers.

Of course, I could respond to their comments by adding my own comments to their answers saying something like

> I just added some additional details, please look up the question field above

but that may sound a little bit impolite - they have already lost some of their time once when they looked up my question only to find that the description was not comprehensive, and now they are asked to go to that page again and look up those additional details in the upper section.

It seems to me that it would be more practical and, perhaps, more appropriate, if they were able to know those additional details directly from my comments added to their answers as those comments (the first few lines of those comments, actually) will be seen to them in their account's summary page (the one that you get to by clicking the envelope icon right next to your name), and, thus, they will know whether or not they could contribute anything to solving my problem without going to my question page.

And finally, if I add additional details both in the upper section of the page and in all the comments to their answers (and their comments), it will make the page unnecessarily overloaded with redundant information, which will be overwhelming both for me and those who will be reading this page in the future.

Comment: My God, that's a lot of text in your question!

Comment: I am sorry. I just didn't know how to make myself clear briefly.

Comment: Start with contractions ("I'm sorry") ;) :)

Comment: @bobobobo: English isn't exactly everyone's strongest language...

Comment: It was a joke.  Hence BOTH the winking face AND smiley face.. I doubled up there JUST IN CASE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the additional information to the question body, maybe marked with **edit:**. That way all people that in the future will answer the question do not have to read all the comments made in question and answers.

People that asked you for more information will likely come back later. If you doubt that or have had a while to add the additional info, add a comment to the answers stating: "Added the info you asked for - see question".

You are right that it would be easier for people asking for more info if it were put in the comment - but then these sites are about building a great information platform. Future users should be able to get most use out of it.

If the additional question gets altered such that answers given on the previous version are rendered invalid, but they perfectly answered the question as stated before, maybe you are better of to ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Note that editing your question pushes it to the top of the question stack again, pretty much guaranteeing it will get some additional attention.

Comment: What about adding comments?

Comment: @bobob Nope.  Commenting does not bump a question.

Comment: @Justin:  Please do not be lazy with my name ;)

Comment: @bobobobo Well, if you want others to use your proper name, you should probably do the same `;)`